# Installing Firebase Pods to my project and getting a terminal error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Programming Novice here, I hope you all are having a good Monday. I've been trying to install these pods to my project and I keep getting an error. It was telling me this...

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

I fixed that by opening it in Xcode and just changing the quotes, but now I can't figure out the next step. I'm trying to install Firebase's Database, Auth, and Storage, but I don't see Storage pop up when I try to pod install. Should I be concerned about that, because its in my podfile.

```
Darins-MacBook-Pro:ExteriorBuildingProducts DAW$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `Pod' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fac9a518670>.

 #  from /Users/DAW/Desktop/Under Development/EXTBP/ExteriorBuildingProducts/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Podfile:8
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  Pod 'Firebase/Database'
 #  Pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pod` command is lowercase. Try changing `Pod` to `pod` inside your `Podfile`.

Comment: Omg... I feel like a total Novice now. Thank you so much!